# What happens to tree stumps in Don't Starve?

Tags: dont-starve

When cutting trees in Don't Starve I don't want to reach a point in the game where my world is terrible and flat, without any trees in it. I usually leave the stumps and use the pine cones to build a forest around my own camp (to protect it, and the pigmen in it)

What happens to the stumps left behind after cutting a tree? Does a tree eventually grow from those stumps, or should I dig out the tree and plant a new one instead? I know the latter is more efficient but it also leaves me with less pine cones.

Comment: What is this game, and where do i find it?

Comment: @Paralytic the game is [Don't Starve](http://www.dontstarvegame.com) (the tag is a hint). It's currently in beta - release is in a few days, but you can buy (and play) it now for a small discount. It's a survival game based on crafting with simple combat and exploration and an unusual, creepy, 'pencil-art' graphics style.

Comment: gonna add your description to the tag @Ian

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Stumps do not regrow](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/showthread.php?2409-Gameplay-Chopped-trees-will-not-regrow), your only option is to plant pine cones to replace them. If left they will simply remain as an obstacle on the map until you dig them up with a shovel or burn them.

Comment: I accepted this one, thanks. It's sad that I have to use the pine cones that they give me but I should find a way to farm them.

Comment: @Bugster in general you tend to get more Pine Cones than you started with, the real issue is running out of flint to make axes.

Comment: @Bugster farming trees is never a problem: try to cut only the bigger trees and you'll get 3 logs + 1 from the stump and 2 pine cones. This way you'll get 2 trees for every one you cut and, as Ian said, you'll only have to worry about running out of materials for the axes.

Comment: Is this maybe outdated, I'm fairly sure that they *now* grow back?

Comment: @Bobby You may be right; I haven't played in quite a while. If you can find a source I'll update my answer. Or you can post your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from digging a stump with **1 use of a shovel**, which would get you just **1 log**, you can set the stump on fire and get **1 ash** instead. That can save you a lot of time, but be sure to control the fire by first digging out the stumps in a desired perimeter. Wind will blow away an ash pile after 20 seconds of it lying on the ground.

Or don't bother limiting the fire zone and just set the world on fire to get some additional burned trees, each of which get you **1 charcoal** and an occasional pinecone for just **1 axe hit**.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, nothing happens to a stump over time.  As you pointed out, you can remove stumps by digging them up with a shovel.